# Google Script for line chart.

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, google-sheets, google-visualization

I want to create line chart (dashboard) using google script for the data that looks like this - [Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fmbtvc2nM06L1t6T-un_q3LGtEDY-3fzOJ-NxbtxwGU/edit#gid=0). I want to plot the line chart for price saved (col D) against Total weight ordered (col E) with the category filter of suppliers (col A).

I tried editing the code available online (shown below), but I have been getting several errors. For example - ReferenceError: "data" is not defined. (line 9, file "Code"). It would be of great help if someone could help me to get rid of these errors.

PS: I don’t have any knowledge of programming and so have posted this question which seems to be bit subjective.

```js
 function doGet() {
      var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
      var ssKey = ("1fmbtvc2nM06L1t6T-un_q3LGtEDY-3fzOJ-NxbtxwGU");
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fmbtvc2nM06L1t6T-un_q3LGtEDY-3fzOJ-NxbtxwGU');
      var sss = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
     
   
      var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();
          for( var j in data[0])
          dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, data[0][j]);
           for( var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i )
           dataTable.addRow(data[i].map(String));
   
   
      var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable);
      
  
      var supplierFilter = Charts.categoryFilter()
          .setFilterColumnLabel("Supplier")
          .build();


      var chartBuilder = Charts.newLineChart()
       .setTitle('price vs volume')
       .setXAxisTitle('price Saved')
       .setYAxisTitle('Total Price')
       .setDimensions(600, 500)
       .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
       .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.MEDIUM);
       
   
      var chart = chartBuilder.build();
   

 
      var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
          .setDataTable(dataTable)
          .bind([supplierFilter], [lineChart])
          .build();
      
   dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
            .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                 .add(supplierFilter)
                 .setSpacing(70))
            .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                 .add(pieChart).add(tableChart)
                 .setSpacing(10)));
      uiApp.add(dashboard);
  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

UiApp is deprecated. Try to use following tutorial
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#sheet-name